# How are mikva fees set?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

Mikva fees seem high relative to swimming pool fees (iun the USA).  For example, two local swimming pools near me charge under $10 while the mikvaot charge $20-$30+.  What factors do or should go into the setting of mikva fees? For example, are mikvaot expected to make a profit, break even, or be a community service?  If break even, what are the ongoing and upkeep expenses for a mikva?

Comment: Probably "what the market will bear” + 10% :-)

Comment: Do you ask about Israel that most Mikvahs belong to the Ministery of Religion or the rest of the world where the Mikvahs are private?

Comment: As a public service a community is obligated to build, How is it different from a shul?

Comment: @AlBerko, no-one charges you for davening with a minyan in a schul three times a day, whereas mikvaot here have fees, which implies that they are not suggested donations

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I asked how is a Mikve different from a shul as being a public obligation? You're right that de-facto there's  a difference, but it seems just a Minhag. A fee could be charged for davening also, wasn't it the case with Hilel?